# creating session array in my shopping cart not functioning

Tags: php, arrays, session, cart

hello I am trying to create a simple shopping cart for my school project the problem I have was the session array is not creating and array with information. So I can't add items on my cart. here is my code.

```php
if(isset($_POST['add_to_cart'])) {
    
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
        
        $session_array_id = array_column($_SESSION['cart'], 'id');
        
            if(!in_array($_GET['id'], $session_array_id)) {
        $session_array = array(
            'id' => $_GET['id'],
            'name' => $_POST['name'],
            'price' => $_POST['price'],
            'quantity' => $_POST['quantity']            
        );
        
        $_SESSION['cart'][0]= $session_array;
                
            }
            
    }else {
        $session_array = array(
            'id' => $_GET['id'],
            'name' => $_POST['name'],
            'price' => $_POST['price'],
            'quantity' => $_POST['quantity']            
        );
        
        $_SESSION['cart'][] = $session_array;
        
    }
```

[image: This is what I am getting.. It won't add another session array]
the picture above is just overwriting my selection everytime I press add to cart it won't stack up new item on top of the other. so basically the session array stays 0 all the time.

Pls somebody help me figure this out thank you so much!

Comment: Have you called `session_start()` somewhere in your code before accessing `$_SESSION`? https://www.php.net/session_start

Answer (score 0):

When you do `$_SESSION['cart'][0]= $session_array;` you set it always on index 0. Try

```
array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $session_array);
```

Also this is not sticking `$_SESSION['cart'][] = $session_array;`

Always trust in array push.